# How does the additively weighted Voronoi algorithm differs from the unweighted Voronoi algorithm?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to read Fortune's description of his additively weighted Voronoi algorithm but I am experiencing some difficulty in understanding it.

I imagine the algorithm as being like that for regular voronoi diagrams with beach line parabolas of different sizes as to take into account the point weights but if that's the case I am not sure how the edges of the resulting weighted voronoi diagram aren't straight lines.

Can someone explain the additively weighted version of [Fortune's algorithm](https://gi.cebitec.uni-bielefeld.de/_media/teaching/2013summer/936fortune-1987-voronoi.pdf)?

Comment: The locus of equal distance to two points takes the form Da + Wa = Db + Wb or Da - Db = Cst. This defines an hyperbola, not a parabola.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes.Does this imply that the beach line for the weighted voronoi algorithm is composed of hyperbolic segments?

Comment: No, you are right. The beach line is still the projection of the intersection of the sweeping plane and cones with their apex at the site, with a vertical offset, and the intersections are parabolas. The difference with unweighted Voronoi is a displacement of the apexes, hence of the vertices of the parabolas.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you understand the algorithm for the weighted voronoi diagram of Fortune can you explain it here.(I am hoping that the algorithm is something like the one for the regular voronoi with modified parabolas where only the endpoints for each edge of the diagram are computed and then the hyperbolic sections are computed thereafter from these endpoints and point weights).

Comment: All I can say is that the cones a displaced vertically, which can modify the order of the events.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would be glad to you if you can read the paper and explain it here in high level language.

Comment: You are asking too much.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please think about it. I can't find any material on this and can't read it.